# Почему логическая операция дает такой результат?

Tags: python

Python 3. Есть переменная a = 1 и c = 1
Выражение a is b дает предсказуемое True. 
Но выражение a is b and 1 выдает в результате не True/False, а число 1. Как это объяснить?

Comment: Прочитать документацию https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html

Comment: Если слева от and истинное выражение и справа истинное выражение, то and выдаёт то что справа. А справа стоит 1

Comment: Вы считаете предсказуемым `a is b == True`? Попробуйте `a` и `b` присвоить значение 1000 и проверить, какой теперь будет результат выражения `a is b`.

Comment: Sergey Gornostaev, действительно! Можете сказать, почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0):

Как выяснилось, это выражение действительно проверяет истинность левой части и если выражение истина, то возвращает то, что справа. Но если вначале добавить if, то выражение `if a is b and 1:` вернут True и выполнит код после двоеточия

Comment: `if a == b == 1` ?

Comment: Оно не вернет тру, if 1: также выпонится

Comment: Да, я имел ввиду, что выражение будет истинным и if выполнится

Comment: Потому что 1 - значение, сводимое к истинному.